# TextView.setText() throws null pointer exception

Tags: java, android, android-layout, user-interface, textview

Hello and nice to meet you guys. I've got an issue that's been troubling me for 2 days straight. Let me get to the point.

I have 2 activities, the first one fills a static Hashtable and in the second one i want to (inside the onCreate method of the second activity and after the setContentView())

```
        TextView name=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.ForeignUserName);
```

and then on the onResume()

```
    name.setText("ASDFASD");
    Personal_Message.setText("sdfgsfgsf");
    Facebook.setText("adfads");
    Email.setText("adsfads");
    Mobile.setText("adsfadsf");
    AdditionalInformation.setText("sdfads");
```

(the "asdfasd" strings are just for debugging i'll be Hashtable.get(i) later)

the first TextView name is filled but the other ones throw Null Pointer Exception.
I've searched the whole StackOverflow. I am sure i'm missing something pretty simple. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

xml

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/ForeignProfileActivityLayout"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ForeignImageView01"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/Profile_Image"
        android:cropToPadding="true"
        android:maxHeight="100dp"
        android:maxWidth="100dp"
        android:minHeight="100dp"
        android:minWidth="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/person" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ForeignPersonalMessage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ForeignUserName"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/Personal_Message"
         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ForeignUserEmail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ForeignFacebookPage"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/email"
         />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ForeignMobileNumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ForeignUserEmail"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/Your_mobile_phone_number"
         />




    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ForeignUserInfo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ForeignMobileNumber"
        android:ems="10"
        android:height="100dp"
        android:hint="@string/Additional_Information"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ForeignUserName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/Your_Name" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ForeignFacebookPage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ForeignPersonalMessage"
        android:layout_marginTop="86dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/FBPage" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

ForeignProfile.java

```
public class ForeignProfile extends Activity {
    TextView name,Facebook,Email,AdditionalInformation,Mobile,Personal_Message;
    AdView adView;
    static final String MYD_AD_UNIT_ID="-----------";

    static final String TAG="ForeignProfile";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        BugSenseHandler.initAndStartSession(this, "-----");

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_foreign_profile);
        Personal_Message=new TextView(getApplicationContext());

        adView=new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, MYD_AD_UNIT_ID);
        RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.ForeignProfileActivityLayout);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT); // check this out
        layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        adView.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
        layout.addView(adView,layoutParams);
        AdRequest req=new AdRequest();
        req.addTestDevice("----------");
        adView.loadAd(req);

        Log.d(TAG, "Foreign Profile Created");
        name=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.ForeignUserName);
        Personal_Message=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.personalMessage);
        Facebook=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.ForeignFacebookPage);
        Email=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.ForeignUserEmail);
        Mobile=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.ForeignMobileNumber);
        AdditionalInformation=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.ForeignUserInfo);



    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        adView.destroy();
        super.onDestroy();

        }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        name.setText("ASDFASD");
        Personal_Message.setText("sdfgsfgsf");
        Facebook.setText("adfads");
        Email.setText("adsfads");
        Mobile.setText("adsfadsf");
        AdditionalInformation.setText("sdfads");




        super.onResume();
    }





}
```

Comment: it means textview initialization fails giving NPE

Comment: post your xml wher you have textviews and the code where you initialize your textviews

Comment: like name TextView have you referenced your other textview's (Personal_Message, Facebook, ... ) via findViewById?

Comment: @GeorgeDaramouskas post the activity code also

Comment: the @id in the xml is android:id="@+id/ForeignPersonalMessage", it is wrong in your java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the below in xml

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/ForeignPersonalMessage" // id is ForeignPersonalMessage
```

Change the below

```
Personal_Message=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.personalMessage);
```

to

```
Personal_Message=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.ForeignPersonalMessage);
```

Comment: That was it. Thanks Raghunandan! i can't believe i missed this! Again thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to:

```
TextView facebook=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.ForeignFacebookPage);
facebook.setText("adfads");
```

for Facebook, Email, Mobile, and AdditionalInformation.

Comment: No its initialized properly as far i can see in the question posted